# TypeError: obj.hasOwnProperty is not a function at each

Tags: node.js, firebase-realtime-database, graphql, apollo-server

I have a problem sending an argument

***schema***

```
  extend type AdminMutation {
    addQuestions(questions: [QuestionsInput!]!): FailureSuccess!
  }
```

***request***

```
mutation {
  admin {
    addQuestions(
      questions: [
         {
          question: "what will we see in the console ?"
          answers: ["1 1", "undefined undefined", "undefined 1", "Error"]
          correctAnswer: "undefined 1"
          img: "/js/1.png"
          point: 6
        }
      ]
    )
  }
}
```

when i try to save question i get error

***resolvers***

```
7    async function addQuestions(
8      { questions }: { questions: [QuestionsInput] },
9      { db }: Context
10    ) {
11      try {
12        await db.ref("/question").push({
13          date: moment().format("MMMM Do YYYY, h:mm:ss a"),
14          questions,
15        });
16      } catch (error) {
17        console.log(error);
18      }
19    }
```

```
  >TypeError: obj.hasOwnProperty is not a function
    at each (C:\Users\darkc\Desktop\\server\node_modules\firebase-admin\node_modules\@firebase\database\src\core\util\util.ts:416:13)
    at validateFirebaseData (C:\Users\darkc\Desktop\\server\node_modules\firebase-admin\node_modules\@firebase\database\src\core\util\validation.ts:185:5)
    at C:\Users\darkc\Desktop\\server\node_modules\firebase-admin\node_modules\@firebase\database\src\core\util\validation.ts:204:7    at each (C:\Users\darkc\Desktop\\server\node_modules\firebase-admin\node_modules\@firebase\database\src\core\util\util.ts:417:7)
    at validateFirebaseData (C:\Users\darkc\Desktop\\server\node_modules\firebase-admin\node_modules\@firebase\database\src\core\util\validation.ts:185:5)
    at C:\Users\darkc\Desktop\\server\node_modules\firebase-admin\node_modules\@firebase\database\src\core\util\validation.ts:204:7    at each (C:\Users\darkc\Desktop\\server\node_modules\firebase-admin\node_modules\@firebase\database\src\core\util\util.ts:417:7)
    at validateFirebaseData (C:\Users\darkc\Desktop\\server\node_modules\firebase-admin\node_modules\@firebase\database\src\core\util\validation.ts:185:5)
    at validateFirebaseDataArg (C:\Users\darkc\Desktop\\server\node_modules\firebase-admin\node_modules\@firebase\database\src\core\util\validation.ts:122:3)
    at Reference.push (C:\Users\darkc\Desktop\\server\node_modules\firebase-admin\node_modules\@firebase\database\src\api\Reference.ts:336:5)
```

How can I fix this error ?

Comment: are you sure the error is because of the code you posted?

Comment: @depperm  Yes, I am sure

Comment: what line is the error occurring on specifically (because we don't have all your code a line number won't help but a comment saying where it occurs might help)?

Comment: @depperm I updated you can look again

Comment: Which version of the Firebase SDK are you using for this? If it's not the latest, do you still get this error after updating to the latest?